# unity raycast CS1003: ',' expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

While trying to raycast i cannot get this to work, ivee tride changing symbols, ive tried using raycasthit outside and passing it through. i just cant get it to work..

```
public int count = 0;
public Transform origin;
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse1))
    {
        Physics.Raycast(origin.position , RaycastHit hitinfo);
        if (hitinfo.collider.tag == "enemy")
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `RaycastHit hitinfo` - there, you are declaring a variable instead of providing one. i recommend [reading the manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) about how to use the method. but as a first step, remove the `RaycastHit` .

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare a RaycastHit - and this of course outside your Physics.Raycast call.

See this code from unity documentation - you can also pass in a layer mask:

```
using UnityEngine;
// C# example.

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    // See Order of Execution for Event Functions for information on FixedUpdate() and Update() related to physics queries
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Bit shift the index of the layer (8) to get a bit mask
        int layerMask = 1 << 8;

        // This would cast rays only against colliders in layer 8.
        // But instead we want to collide against everything except layer 8. The ~ operator does this, it inverts a bitmask.
        layerMask = ~layerMask;

        RaycastHit hit;
        // Does the ray intersect any objects excluding the player layer
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.yellow);
            Debug.Log("Did Hit");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 1000, Color.white);
            Debug.Log("Did not Hit");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no overload function for

`Physics.Raycast(origin.position , RaycastHit hitinfo);`

Meaning that there are many things you can put into the Raycast function, but a `(Vector3, RaycastHit)` is not one of the combinations. I regularly use the following method:

```
/* Define the point of origin for the raycast */
var origin = transform.position; // From the player

/* Define the direction the raycast will be going in from the origin */
var dir = transform.forward; // Infront of the player

/* Define a ray */
Ray ray = new Ray(origin, dir);

/* Create a storage for the results */
HitInfo hit;

/* Check to see if we hit something */
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
    // Yes we did hit something
    print("We hit an object");
}
```

If we put this into a propper function to get the tag the camera is looking at:

```
public string GetTagOfLookingAt () {
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.Main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
        return hit.gameobject.tag;
    } else {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```